# should I use Object.assign on hook variables in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner in react and I have read that we shouldn't update hook variables directly but via `setState` . With my code I assign a state variable as an object  to another variable and then I `console.log` it . Is this a bad practice since it exposes my `item` hook variable  ?

```
const [item,setItem] = useState({fruit:'apples'});
let dummy = Object.assign({},item); //is this a bad practice ? 
console.log(dummy);
```

I am using `Object.assign()` to clone the object  so that it won't be mutated by just pointing to it like `dummy = item;` and then changing `dummy.fruit` which will change `item.fruit`.

I am sorry if this feels like a bad question but I am curious

Comment: Very weird. It would be better to just *not have* other code that attempts to mutate the stateful value.

Comment: More context would be helpful. Why do you need to clone and mutate the clone?

Comment: @OriDrori I am setting the clone as a state variable with useState

Comment: Please add an example of the state, and how you update it after cloning.

Answer (score 2):

No its not a bad practice. We should never mutate the state directly. So the right way is to create a copy and then do the updation we need.
So in your case,

```
const [item,setItem] = useState({fruit:'apples'});
let dummy = Object.assign({},item);
// Now you can do whatever changes you need to dummy
dummy.fruit = "mango";
// and then update the state with this clone
setItem(dummy);
```